# Movie where contestants have to kill one another for money

Tags: horror, identify-this-movie

So my memory is pretty bad, but.. i believe it was filmed in early 2000s.
  It's a movie about a reality tv type show where contestants are trapped inside a gorgeous villa and have to kill each other for money (I believe the protagonist was a young blond woman)
  Anyway, she wins (duuh), but there's a plot twist: she walks out of the villa with a bag of money in her hands, only to walk into another villa, with like 5-15 more paranoid people, each with a bag full of money in her hands.

Answer (score 14):

Probably [House of Nine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395585/). The lead is [Kelly Brook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_Brook).

The description you provided matches the plot in the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_9).

> Nine strangers have been abducted and locked inside a house. A
>   mysterious voice called The Watcher (voiced by Jim Carter) tells them
>   that they are to play a game: the last person alive can leave the
>   house and win five million dollars. The film is presented with "live
>   feeds" from hidden surveillance cameras, showing the nine people
>   turning from cooperative escape attempts to a killing fest.

There are two alternate endings listed but I think this is the one you described:

> In the second "originally intended" ending, as Lea leaves the house, she is >led into another house where she meets
>   four people. Each of them has a bag of money. The camera zooms in on
>   Lea; a fearful look grows as she realizes that the game is not over.

Comment: @Lina Please, mark this answer as accepted. [Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like it could be Would You Rather, the same situation and the main character is a blonde gal, but it came out in 2012

Comment: Can you provide a source to back up your answer?

Answer (score -4):

Well of coarse the saw franchise would be the ultimate answer to this but I'm guessing people want a more obscure answer so I would probably say 'the killing room' or 'exam' << although its not really about dieing but more about being 'disqualified' I strongly recommend those two.. if not then a third option may be a film called 'breathing space' where 10 total strangers have to kill each other in order to stay alive, also there some excellent twits and unique things that make it a one-of-a-kind film even though there are some other films with this storyline this film is so unique it will feel like you've never seen nothing like it...